Optionally validating nested fields depending on database field
I working on NestJS app and trying to validate some field depending on other field.
export class CreateOrderDTO {
  @IsDeliveryCodeValid() // Custom validator
  delivery_code: string;

  @IsAddressRequired() // Custom validator
  @IsNotEmptyObject()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => CreateOrderAddressDTO)
  address: CreateOrderAddressDTO;
}

In this code, delivery_code is unique id of DeliveryType which has needAddress boolean field. I want to validate address only if this needAddress field is set to true.
What I'm trying to achieve is create some custom decorator which checks if provided delivery_code is code of one of delivery types and if found delivery type has needAddress field set to true, if so we have to validate address, otherwise we can ignore validators.
My ideas:

It could be done in controller but I really want to check this at CreateOrderDTO level.
Somehow transform whole DTO before validators run and add field needAddress to it's body so validators can access it.
Manually transform DTO at @IsDeliveryCodeValid() decorator and add field needAddress to DTO body. It's not really elegant way because I dont think i should transform dto in validators, it's not their purpose and can be confusing.

Normally i would use @ValidateIf() but it doesnt accept async functions, so i can't use a DB query here.
Thanks for your help!

I tried to solve this problem by:
S1: Create a custom validator @IsDeliveryCodeValid() to verify the delivery_code and add the needAddress value to the DTO
S2: Use @ValidateIf() to check whether the address needs to be validated based on the needAddress value or not
is-delivery-code-valid.validator.ts


import {
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface,
  ValidationArguments,
  registerDecorator,
  ValidationOptions,
} from 'class-validator';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DeliveryService } from './delivery.service';

@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
@Injectable()
export class IsDeliveryCodeValidConstraint
  implements ValidatorConstraintInterface
{
  constructor(private readonly deliveryService: DeliveryService) {}

  async validate(code: string, args: ValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
    const dto = args.object as any;
    const deliveryType = await this.deliveryService.getDeliveryTypeByCode(code);
    if (deliveryType) {
      dto.needAddress = deliveryType.needAddress;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  defaultMessage(): string {
    return 'Invalid delivery code!';
  }
}

export function IsDeliveryCodeValid(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      constraints: [],
      validator: IsDeliveryCodeValidConstraint,
    });
  };
}



create-order.dto.ts


import {
  ValidateIf,
  ValidateNested,
  IsNotEmptyObject,
} from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { CreateOrderAddressDTO } from './create-order-address.dto';
import { IsDeliveryCodeValid } from './is-delivery-code-valid.validator';

export class CreateOrderDTO {
  @IsDeliveryCodeValid({ message: 'Invalid delivery code' })
  delivery_code: string;

  @ValidateIf((o) => o.needAddress) 
  @IsNotEmptyObject({ message: 'Address is required' })
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => CreateOrderAddressDTO)
  address: CreateOrderAddressDTO;

  needAddress?: boolean; // This field is dynamically attached by IsDeliveryCodeValid validator
}




This would work i guess. The question is will this validator run and complete before address validators? For now I came up with different solution, propanly more ugly :D I'll attach it in another comment

For now i moved whole validation to IsAddressRequiredConstraint which propably solves my problem but it's something that changes my general aproach to validation and it's confusing.
@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
@Injectable()
export class IsAddressValidConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(protected readonly deliveryTypeService: DeliveryTypeService) {}

  async validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
    const dto = args.object as any;
    const delivery_code = dto.delivery_code;

    const delivery_code_valid =
      isDefined(delivery_code) &&
      isString(delivery_code) &&
      minLength(delivery_code, 3) &&
      maxLength(delivery_code, 32);

    if (!delivery_code_valid) return false;

    const deliveryType = await this.deliveryTypeService.findOneByCode(delivery_code);

    // We dont need to check address
    if (!deliveryType.need_address) return true;

    // Check if address is is defined and it's not empty
    if (!isDefined(value) || !isNotEmptyObject(value)) return false;

    // Validate with CreateOrderAddressDTO
    const addressDTO = plainToInstance(CreateOrderAddressDTO, value);
    const errors = await validate(addressDTO);

    return errors.length === 0;
  }

The problem with this approach is thay i make a two calls this.deliveryTypeService.findOneByCode(delivery_code), one while checking delivery_code and one while checking address.
